# ERROR Missing binding app/nodes_modules/node-sass

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, system, node-modules

**When i use :**

> $ yarn run production

**I get this error (for each .scss files present in the project) :**

> ERROR in ./resources/assets/sass/guest.scss Module
>   build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Missing
>   binding /app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-48/binding.node
>   Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux
>   64-bit with Node.js 6.x
>
> Found bindings for the following environments:
>     - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x

**What i tried :**

> $ npm rebuild node-sass
>
> $ npm rebuild node-sass --force
>
> $ rm -rf package-lock.json
>
> $ rm -rf node-modules
>
> $ npm install

**But i get the same error, anyone have an idea ? Thank you !**

Answer (score 0):

Logs show that your version is **Node.js 6.x** but the Node Sass requires **Node.js 8.x.**

You can either do one of the following:

1. Upgrade your node version to 8.x.
2. Downgrade your Sass dependency to the one compatible with Node.js 6.x